# How to configure ROLE prefix Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory

Good day collegues.
Have tried to use diffirent variant but nothing happened.

I have an a code where is next method:

```
public List<String> getUserRoles() {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()) {
            roles.add(authority.getAuthority().toUpperCase());
        }

        return roles;
    }
```

I want to get all user authirities from Active Directory, but get only with **prefix "ROLE_"**

I tried:

1. Use application.yaml + code(prefix in yaml==null):

   method(AbstractContextSource ldapContext,
                                   AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder)...

   ```
   builder.ldapAuthentication()
          .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(populator)
          .contextSource(ldapContext)
          .userSearchFilter(userSearchFilter)
          .userSearchBase(userSearchBase)
          .groupSearchBase(groupSearchBase)
          .groupSearchFilter(groupSearchFilter)
          .rolePrefix(rolePrefix);
   ```

   It doesnt work.

2.different custom classes doesnt work too.

My question is how to get all roles without prefix ROLE_.

Answer (score 4):

Here two approaches if you use `hasRole` to do authorization:

Javaconfig

```
@Bean
    public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setDefaultRolePrefix("");
        return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
}
```

XML config

```
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultRolePrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
```

Or you can use `hasAuthority()` instead of `hasRole()`. the previous one will not add `PREFIX` when doing accessing check.

Comment: One example of my config using hasAuthority: antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRADOR")

Comment: thanks, i used hasAuthority and worked